# how to solve bug in Tcp server

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket, tcpserver

Following is "TCP SERVER" code, when any client connect first time the code is run very well, but once that client disconnect and again connect with TCP SERVER, than client connects successfully but can not send data.

How to detect client is disconnected with server?

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.CountDownTimer;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.net.Inet4Address;
 import java.net.Inet6Address;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.NetworkInterface;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Enumeration;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     TextView tvStatus;
     EditText etPort, etMsg, etTransmit;
     Button btnListen, btnServerSend;
     Handler UIHandler;

     private int SERVERPORT1;
     private InetAddress addr;
     private ServerSocket serverSocket;
     private Socket clientSocket = null;
     private BufferedReader in;
     private PrintWriter out;

     //    public static final int SERVERPORT = 3000;
     private WifiManager wifiManager = null;
     private WifiManager.WifiLock lock = null;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         wifi();
         UIHandler = new Handler();
         tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

         etMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMsg);
         etTransmit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTransmit);
         etPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPort);

         btnListen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListen);
         btnServerSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnServerSend);
 //  ******************* Register controls end ******************************

         btnListen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 new ServerClass().execute(etPort.getText().toString());
             }
         });
     }

     public String getLocalIpAddress() throws Exception {
         String resultIpv6 = "";
         String resultIpv4 = "";

         for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
              en.hasMoreElements(); ) {

             NetworkInterface intf = (NetworkInterface) en.nextElement();
             for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();
                  enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {

                 InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress) enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                 if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                     if (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                         resultIpv4 = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                     } else if (inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address) {
                         resultIpv6 = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return ((resultIpv4.length() > 0) ? resultIpv4 : resultIpv6);
     }

     private class ServerClass extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {
         private String input;

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            SERVERPORT1 = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            addr = InetAddress.getByName(getLocalIpAddress());
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT1, 0, addr);

            while (true) {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    tvStatus.setText(clientSocket.getInetAddress().toString() + " Client connected");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    input = in.readLine();
                    if (input != null) {
                        UIHandler.post(new updateUIThread1(input.toString()));
                        out.println("Received from client: " + input);
                    } else {
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                new ServerClass().execute(etPort.getText().toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
     }

     private class updateUIThread1 implements Runnable {
         private String input = null;

         public updateUIThread1(String input) {
             this.input = input;
         }

         @Override
         public void run() {
             if (input.getBytes().length != 0) {
                 etMsg.append("\n" + input.toString());
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Answer: " + input, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

> Log shows like:

```
04-22 12:57:05.799 10857-10931/com.chat.admin.clientserver I/System.out: [CDS]shutdownInput in read
04-22 12:57:05.799 10857-10931/com.chat.admin.clientserver I/System.out: [CDS]shutdownInput in read
04-22 12:57:05.799 10857-10931/com.chat.admin.clientserver I/System.out: [CDS]shutdownInput in read
04-22 12:57:05.799 10857-10931/com.chat.admin.clientserver I/System.out: [CDS]shutdownInput in read
04-22 12:57:05.799 10857-10931/com.chat.admin.clientserver I/System.out: [CDS]shutdownInput in read

                                                                     read: unexpected EOF!
```

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a new server if a client disconnects.

Instead you should have a loop so you can call .accept() again to wait for a new client.

Comment: i'm newbie, so can you please explain in detail or mention in your answer.

Comment: I will not. Please try to add a while(true) loop starting with the accept() statement. Edit your post so we can see what you do.

Comment: partially solved but only one message is received at server in each connection. latency is increased. please check my updated code.                        Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CodeBreaker That's because you're only reading one line per incoming connection. You don't appear to understand your own code.

Comment: Dear, @EJP  yes i know why i'm getting one line, i need to use "while loop" but it read all data only one connection. i already said i'm newbie and i don't have enough time to complete this. please understand me.